# sharepoint 2013 search user vote

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I'm using SharePoint Server 2013 to crawl enterprise documents.

Now I need to give end users a way to vote for search results. That votes are going to influence on future search queries (documents promotes up or down).

Is there a way to implement it?